# How to load keywords from two languages in lstlisting?

Tags: listings, code, lua

I know how to define two different styles for two different languages in lstlisting package. I want to include keywords from **Lua** as well as **LaTeX** in the **same** style. Is it possible?

```
\lstdefinestyle{myStyle}{
 language = {[5.0]Lua},
keywordstyle=\color{blue},
 basicstyle={\ttfamily}
}
```

I can manually add keywords from TeX or LaTeX in this style with `morekeywords` but it would be cumbersome.

Comment: Can you please, as always, make your code fit to compile? Thank you